# "This solution contains packages with vulnerabilities" - How do I determine which packages contains vulnerabilities?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

Visual Studio shows me the following warning when I open the solution explorer:

[image]

When I click the 'Manage NuGet Packages' link and scroll through the nuget packages, I can't see any indication of exactly what packages contains vulnerabilities. How do I figure out exactly what packages contains vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you do a "Manage NuGet Packages", you should see an option "Show only vulnerable" (at least I do in my VS 2022 v17.8.2):

[image]

Make sure to also select "nuget.org" as the package source, since "All" doesn't appear to list any vulnerable packages (with VS v17.8.3):

[image]

Comment: In addition, I also had to ensure that the Package source was set to Nuget.org, and not our internal package manager.

Comment: also is there any setting to not show this warning?

Comment: I have the same issue, and when I click "Show only vulnerable", there is nothing in the filtered list, even though the yellow icon is still present next to the "Installed" tab title...

Comment: @dkimbell13: I faced the same issue. The solution was to select each package source. With "All" selected, no vulnerable packages were shown (I have both nuget.org and multiple internal feeds available), but when I specifically selected "nuget.org" the vulnerable packages appeared.

Comment: @Julian
That almost worked! I did as you said, (switched to nuget.org), and the vulnerable package showed up. I fixed it, and the yellow icon showed up again, and once again when I click the "Show only vulnerable" there is nothing in the list.... NO ideal what is causing this issue...